# ASP.NET c# error 404.15 when submitting a form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created a form in asp.net webforms but every time I try and submit the form I get the following error.

> The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured
>   maxQueryStringLength value.

I have tried increasing this value but I cannot seem to get it to submit.

This is the query string that the form is creating

```
http://localhost:3819/accidentreportform.aspx?__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%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%2FbojQb3B%2FC%2FSKj3kkzh9h0c%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAJsBHIaiWf9dOuDdXWyjR2puJWwoZW%2FvGw%2BtopxdEzd442ZUIrPaNRt73R7V%2FSDTxgtFL6uIDB0nTnHywmiKhWlLgXuRpe%2BlHPjJ2kpifoNY98NnTzlreH4zduKwHZaVf0H6673RECKl6TEmJGQvuvVIQhVYTdkj4UIxk35Y4KXRFWoZ%2BdSlSkWo%2B%2FOVX4deb6dxP1p%2BvD1jdA%2Bko6BlPG9jZETnkzG2nMnykGeuVpkR%2Bt%2FLC3778xmZZ0NW2XldW3q%2Bd4lIZ3BfMm%2B9jqbvUPKAtbje7jd57SNodx0aRwHt5qs9IwHn6CCY9VPWCdlSagYD5hvo87JmnmbTNYES%2BCfOffpTtH2%2FOHcIoC7hlCFV6YUhUFdwcKyxb2pWpNKnZ475LJ4XMyLKV2EgaJCyfGC9rF6%2FdbxmN%2F8s7sStVjSF1pb%2B3JpztAH7zKlWQld11xoxV3xT1rum2BziOL0T2nIBA7DuCqDdEWUj50ZoCaCWVWfEhMsU%2BmSo1JVHRABlRRdcez0C5Su%2Bnn955RtBTkl946CwxkdV9A7qB0eSI41HIQJ4iYc9bqIzNPk2xof2fC%2BVq6cUz3upJ%2BXyku%2BqtPP4is0Gdu4fGLyzvCtFVvqc4gvyl0Nm6bsSsXjZoz8f%2BertDje9ygUL5PxfdDhNksgW6qEUaC0OVTOw3DLoxwKHxgg4jW8F3QcMPuhqkzYorPng8BYEQoO9EsTST6B7a1FU2ebpn3rMGjs2XIYu51uimP8YyUl2TPzA2vXBzHUtbj%2FcB7iC2eEfubz6zX4pIsGbUr1N7FpXB3aQn7XASa8FfPHDkmYeM0In8XUF5RhGmW7%2BYc4u3H0aPfsT9L5nWCZm3lyVijBsGez5XDbpgxU5tLpSddtdepS1v3EQmmCi%2FBTNCkzAH%2B5dopgqYdS0%2BhocrUPki2peTuRITC5YA%2BbIAS9%2BIpToYv2yhe89bcDgOt3tUi27AMgGbKM6zestJPyQlQeB%2FLbiQg3p86ZGggF3X2%2BdD1BJ%2BCEvwzqxxnRedtP1ZbDf5zjHZbYmG%2FGHRLTOBhoB9VWjBWUyOSoBjG5Zozh7SWRe07%2BIFZeel8vA%2FLrtwPcJcbM67ymB%2B540KDRe7EhVZi8RvuIl4ZxCztppELCNElluJvVeX%2BiRZvD%2Fl%2B%2BRcG3otp0pQ9rUxufFch%2Byj1%2FO6Oy2jFb2h%2BTq0Af7WJPD77FYwbjUI02VSuZuM4a92Xo4oYbmvlREDNm2yNZswphuzK6HlP%2BKoyWQh21CoAqPCSAvF0qTNa2bykmXxJgeG8GSxcQTLxzICqxbo4wBlxJuOovy7dwzeXE2F2OBxJIoe4R5IWX9io2cGr15BCSK0njy%2FWOOzeJjHCOu2io0WIZ3BHq3%2B%2Fz%2FJzW5O1eFbeeXEjW3H2EYmhF9LuTP%2Fi7RYxWLH6HCZGOXmPlm9NnTo1ZwFABjD9dbsu%2BNw5h2zNmYKtMew0MmM1CgKRDMwWCc7yeoWRfsc240sm4EIRmna9xUctkIw97ERMRZryERr1Zmyqg2%2Fpxri7iS8QUCfgzboj%2BY5%2F8TAmP%2F4IIQTu26ncEAYMm1MFPdc%2BUkTTVtFHTpgYv5Z%2BTb2gHhC5miISnX%2FZLcAdw7qoQoLbw86atT%2BPxKRuvJE%2FT8tPqKuoxY0JPNAdFSFiHUBi4jeuZJLS8YYJrbpNSCwnr0zWnMhMj9mEZ0jD9BcDd9SO14bw6uvX4h9ts%2FFAwVtDGYZni0EORWprPjxTOp3rcMi04wbd7qm9xzvzShiQvnZSS5vJqrBgef%2FdHjb0nLiJnccyJMtWVp%2Ffp10%2ByRjVtUcFMYqntRhHEFb64%2B3BB8AmkskF4Xl2hh0HR4cC24YP9NQmpDaEeRuCc23mLWvVkHqLgUgqVGJgX2%2BPF1xMI%2BKfTjC5Sol25aLAPTnIOrpuHu3Z4jipqme1i1lCnikRjSAcL7yBRKtLZXl68S6RM%2F4%2FHH29MuLmpFB9cc5oapETNxFRFwe0dl8x0tFBd5e%2Bw42aN%2BB8wxyCza66nkHdtZYXmhE9qo3zeb0Dl6isprRvcd5GbqZxxDhXw9EjIJGqtHB4KbBGX5zCYCHYOPFXmEYI389HaBq42ZtYvPXQsH5EYEpAXvhMD%2BvfKtrI%2FUprd9RJFXm3wT5kpNSP8P6x%2BXroJFJbvGEMP7caynvm7XztzW9ne2hUqCIanKBW8hZDVeuQGzKlvZzOiPoHt1NsAm077mktGE2GGU0IYY6z%2BZvx7H3peCskahpj2VjoLzta%2By1D60UhP29UOflvCLnzliCWlp8cEV%2BjyWXNoPLvqPETvoae5NxGFAH7KYHFCxYeTVvIdAxiqMrchr6YVKfScM39ciIAdeP4W7k0YRu%2BBpgPnmQH4ylKCVOrHLWWqAe3qDWpOnKJm2xE3UhGV6Lk5a8M72oX5AtG1a4EE3DRCXGnIJNTpSw1uMwFwrpCZq9o%2F9JDXpxA1Q1WnRmek%2BoBR1hafC5WIH%2BHKaYy10dXIe8G1Cpftt7ZfiDOL%2FlRaRoPxT%2B8Pt%2Fhhu83APJe9HeF%2BbVYf69veoP3j3oO8TtuaWdqjMLF1F%2BN%2BmaFJGtWt3UQvhxyk3VRn0HFZVpOW%2FHYhxDWYWenRkk4oUWi4M7dl8gqcfnvj4RYC%2BJXODzxe5IY%2BGSZfXjBy5cJeMhabPmUCNnCQ0KSfoqmfJp2jqZ%2FWwzUYE5nhFB1ICEON7eK9J4GgpS5%2F4qVLPNvsD5wo50TTBE8Cjuyy7ywRl5hN%2FDhpAr1kqqK%2BzsYChxpIqXmi%2BTaBp5F%2BR3x%2BgoNnGr9iCcnqwPeK0km3gFpkP%2BlWqRXDgtwA%2BXGF6vRiisG4PMBOgP1WQtn0Jd53mhORJR4Bpxk6R%2BYWfGLBXECmgEHgzwip9AhDXENQqqR2xkRu4Bp2sLxvW8YAjviZt4XP34e4WPKVens9c%2BA8eD6i7NBQ08WmgcGW%2BLUX6zZPEX5e2xeuu7n5yvbZeYRlNTDzatuKib3eqcah7G4ZX5yRckjVGkL0yhlE5DMIKduVI38BZD2DbvM1OUTQ02sQ9S1wt%2B0VzrPo98js4I4jJUnQzxYfphrTFUofT%2BLPGRtTdkBSopo2anqOglnu42aTeOBoYrjNCfyq%2B5IkzjimPaZvgRVvmVffYEi%2FjqKLvjptN0bVI939Tauu1vyWl%2FvZJEmLTuLvT8VH19zEH015Jv4bDiG1V%2FPfZhLr82KvVD%2Fs%2B%2FFAhYwG33a60HsBv1lvwXX0phIKGhwLzJdwIf1bnE82uRW5wDrUB6A4pB5AoeU6lYdkSU43tWDlDKEuVBS%2BAyow7t%2BaOQlJ%2BrpluCTaRNafRGUwSsEfw%2F3O5Dqj%2B2TYZaXI%2B0udxFUXY%2Bczpj7AFwQ%3D%3D&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24CompleteByInj=on&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24colname=fgh+fgh&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24HNumber=78&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Street=jk&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Town=hjk&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24County=hjk&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Postcode=hjk&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24jobTitle=hjk&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24dd=1&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24mm=1&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24yy=2012&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24hh=0&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24mmm=0&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24AccLocation=hk&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24AccEquipment=hjk&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24AccDetails=hjk&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24AccRecommendations=hjk&SubmitTimeDate=%40DateTime.Now&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Button1=Submit
```

Comment: Why are you doing a GET with view-/event-state variables? Do a POST.

Comment: Ehr. Have you set your form to submit via GET, rather than POST?

Comment: That URL with query string is 7158 characters long. Change your form to do a `POST`, not a `GET`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is submitted as GET means it is set in the location which is restricted to ## chars..

in order to submit longer data: Use 
    `<form method="post">`